# Maven + IntelliJ project settings reset

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, project-settings

At the moment Im trying to learn a little bit about Maven and going into IntelliJ IDEA. I set up a project and created a jersey rest backend with hibernate and mysql. I used tomcat as web container. Everything works, but sometimes I recognise that some settings in my IntelliJ project settings are deleted. Perhaps it has something to do with Maven...?

The two problems I got:

1. Sometimes my application context I set up in the tomcat configuration just disappears.
2. I added the folder src/main/resources in the project settings, because I saved my hibernate config to this folder so maven deploys it in the war. I added also the src folder, because there are all my src files. But after some tomcat restarts, this directory disappears too and then all files in my src folder are marked with a red icon.

This is my pom:

```
    <groupId>ExampleProject</groupId>
<artifactId>ExampleProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
        <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image: IntelliJ Tomcat Configuration]

[image: Project Settings / Module]

Can someone help me and explain why this happens?

Comment: how did you create the project because the maven webapp layout is not the same as shown in your image

Comment: I just created it over IntelliJ as Maven module. But probably I just changed the folder layout on my own. Didnt know that this can result in some weird issues? But as Nebelmann answered below - the project layout is probably my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" layout in a Maven web app is:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    resources/
    webapp/
      WEB-INF/
  test/
    java/
    resources/
```

Your screenshots indicate that your setup is a little different, that's why IntelliJ may be confused and acts strangely. I suggest you create your Maven project using a [predefined archetype](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-webapp/), then import it in IntelliJ (using `File -> Open` and selecting the root `pom.xml`).
I've never had any problems using the standard Maven layout. Furthermore, it follows Maven's convention over configuration and it will be easier to understand for those who are used to standard Maven projects.

Comment: Interesting. Its probably my mistake that I just started to hack around instead of reading some maven documentation =) I will try to find out if it helps if I just rearrange my project setup. Ty!

Comment: Hi Nebelmann, I changed my project layout. Since then I didnt have any suspicious errors =) Ty.